# python3 http.server logging how to

Tags: python-3.x, http

I have created a simple HTTP server of files in the current directory using

```
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

This works very well for downloading files in this directory. Logging output is directed to the terminal window -- I assume to either stdout or stderr

I want to log activity through this server by writing log to a specified file.

I have tried

```
python3 -m http.server 8000 > log.txt 2>&1
```

But this produces an empty `log.txt`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a standard way of doing this or do I have to subclass the `http.server` class? Something like that?

Comment: Command `python3 -m http.server 8000 2> hello.txt` will only write the log to the file once the server exits (e.g. with Ctrl + C).

Comment: Ah! Rats! I suppose I'll have to get under the hood a bit. Oh well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had a look into the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u), you can use:

```
python3 -u -m http.server 8000 2> log.txt
```

The argument `-u` will make it so that **stdout** and **stderr** are not buffered and will be written in real time.

Comment: Perfect. Also I want to run it as a systemd service for a day or so. For this I added `
[Service]
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to the service file and output goes to the systemd journal and to the service `status` output.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working just fine for me. How are you verifying the contents of the log.txt? If you are trying to view the contents of the file while the command is running it will not work. After the command has been KeyboardInterrupted, run

```
cat log.txt | more
```

Should be fine.

Comment: [uuoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), use `more log.txt`